# Периодическое скачивание файла на сервер

Tags: php, javascript, api

Здравствуйте, есть интернет магазин в который нужно добавить товар от поставщиков. Добавление товара осуществляется через `api`. Скачивается файл в формате `xml`. Нужно написать скрипт (желательно на `php`), чтобы этот файл автоматически обновлялся сам раз в день. То есть скрипт по ссылке скачивал файл и размещал его на сервере или заменял старый файл новым раз в день. Как можно это сделать? Можно ли сделать это на `JavaScript` или нужен именно серверный язык?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этих целей целесообразнее всего использовать [Cron](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

**Cron (Command Run ON)** — система для автоматического запуска программ и скриптов на сервере в определённое время ([ист.](http://www.hostcms.ru/documentation/server/crontab/)).

В двух словах:

создайте php файл с функцией загрузки файла на сервер

```
function downloadSrc($file_url, $save_to){
    $content = file_get_contents($file_url);
    file_put_contents($save_to, $content);
}
downloadSrc('target_xml.xml', realpath("path/to/folder/where/xml_nested") . 'file_name.xml');
```

Укажите этот файл в Crone-панели вашего хоста для запуска, с использованием спец.команды (на примере хостинга [ukraine.com.ua](https://www.ukraine.com.ua/?page=246830), путь к виджету на вашем хосте может отличаться):

```
/usr/bin/wget -O - -q -t 1 http://your_awesome_site.com/path/to/cron.php
```

Выставьте частоту выполнения задачи (раз в сутки в вашем случае). Теперь виджет будет автоматом вызывать файл cron.php и выполнять инструкции описываемые в нём.

Интерфейс на разных хостах отличается, но суть одинакова. Для уточнения деталей и нюансов общайтесь с поддержкой вашего хостинга.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать)